# Book where two or three kids are stuck in a video game and have to sneak past a giant at one point

Tags: story-identification, books, video-games

So I read a story in middle school about these two or three kids who went into a video game and got stuck there but had to beat it to get out. I can hardly remember anything about the plot but I know at one point they had to sneak past a giant and they were getting panicked about their lives running out. I swear it had the word revenge in the title but I'm not 100% sure about it.

Comment: holy cow! not only was that stupid fast but you go it on the first try!!! just bought it on amazon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[Rodomonte's Revenge](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21675358-rodomonte-s-revenge)*** (1994) by Gary Paulsen, the second book in the *[World of Adventure](https://www.goodreads.com/series/71917-world-of-adventure)* series.

> *As Brett watched, one hand slipped loose, then the other. Tom dropped, screaming, into the flames. His body, all red and bubbled, boiled up once to the surface, then was gone.
> PLAYER ONE HAS ONE LIFE REMAINING. GAME CONTINUES.*
>
> Flaming fire rivers. Divebombing buzz-bugs. A cruel king waiting to do battle in his computer-generated castle. Video game whizzes Brett Wilder and Tom Houston think that new virtual reality game *Rodomonte’s Revenge* is awesome - until it takes over their minds. Then the game playing becomes dangerously real, and one wrong move could be the last.